# Differences between ip, iptables, ifconfig, ethtool?

Tags: networking

These tools look like they do many similar things. When should I use each one, and what are the differences in their goals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ethtool` controls *Ethernet hardware* and the link layer, such as negotiated link speed, Wake-on-LAN, flow control, and other features.

`ip` configures *IP networking* on Linux – assigns IP addresses to the system, adds routes (including the "default gateway"), creates tunnels (e.g. GRE or 6in4), and such.

`ifconfig` and `route` are the BSD equivalents to Linux `ip`. (They exist on Linux too, but are rapidly becoming out-of-date there.)

`iptables` and `ip6tables` control the Linux *packet filter* (i.e. the firewall). Once networking has been configured in general, iptables (or more recently nft) can block or transform specific kinds of traffic.

Answer (score 2):

These tools allow you to control a huge range of network parameters in Linux and it would be impossible for any answer here to give you a complete breakdown of when and how to use each. You should perform some basic research yourself to get a flavour of what each does. May I suggest:

- [ip man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)
- [ip examples](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ip-command-examples-usage-syntax/)
- [iptables man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)
- [iptables examples](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html)
- [ifconfig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig)
- [ifconfig examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/ifconfig-7-examples-to-configure-network-interface/)
- [ethtool man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool)
- [ethtool examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/ethtool-command/)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)